# My Image class returns null when I try to display an image. How can I fix this?

Tags: java, game-engine, javax.imageio

this is my first time using stack overflow asking a question so I apologize if I haven't formatted correctly; all feedback on that is appreciated.

I have been following a tutorial on Youtube from 2017 by Majoolwip (https://youtu.be/4iPEjFUZNsw), which is written in **Java** using **Eclipse IDE**. In the series he is building a game engine that you can run your games through. He walks you through how to make the windows and take user input, but most importantly for this situation, he is teaching how to display an image file in the window.

The important part is that my **"Image" class** is unable to fetch the url of the image in my **"res" folder**. When I try to run my program with the image it just throws me a 

Which I know is correct because when I print the value of the Image object it prints "null" to my console.

Currently the code that is throwing is in my **"GameManager" class** in which my **Constructor** has a one line that creates a new image object and gives it a string called **"path"** that is set as **"res/test.png"**.

As far as my path variable goes, I have tried many differnt formats for the image i.e. **"/test.png"**, **"/RougeEngine/res/test.png"**, and **"/res/test.png"**; none of them return the image.

The error is seemingly occurring in the creation of the **image object**, using the

**image = ImageIO.read(Image.class.getResourceAsStream(path));** my CS professor thought that perhaps the **class literal** could be the issue, but he isn't all too familiar with **getResourceAsStream()**.

Here's my GameContainer code:

```
package com.RougeEngine.Engine;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

public class GameContainer implements Runnable
{
private Thread thread;
private Window window;
private Renderer renderer;
private Input input;
private AbstractGame game;

private boolean running = false;
private final double UPDATE_CAP = 1.0/60.0;
private int width = 320, height = 240;
private float scale = 3f;
private String Title = "RougeEngine v1.0";

public GameContainer(AbstractGame game)
{
    this.game = game;
}

public void start()
{
    window = new Window(this);
    renderer = new Renderer(this);
    input = new Input(this);

    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.run();
}

public void stop()
{

}

public void run()
{
    running = true;

    boolean render = false;
    double firstTime = 0;
    double lastTime = System.nanoTime() / 1000000000.0;
    double passedTime = 0;
    double unprocessedTime = 0;

    double frameTime = 0;
    int frames = 0;
    int fps = 0;

    while(running)
    {
        render = false;

        firstTime = System.nanoTime() / 1000000000.0;
        passedTime = firstTime - lastTime;
        lastTime = firstTime;

        unprocessedTime = unprocessedTime + passedTime;
        frameTime = frameTime + passedTime;

        while(unprocessedTime >= UPDATE_CAP)
        {
            unprocessedTime = unprocessedTime - UPDATE_CAP;
            render = true;

            game.update(this, (float)UPDATE_CAP);

            input.update();

            if(frameTime >= 1.0)
            {
                frameTime = 0;
                fps = frames;
                frames = 0;
                System.out.println("FPS:"+fps);
            }
        }
        if(render)
        {
            renderer.clear();
            game.render(this, renderer);
            window.update();
            frames++;
        }
        else
        {
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    dispose();
}

private void dispose()
{

}

public int getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public void setWidth(int width) {
    this.width = width;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(int height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public float getScale() {
    return scale;
}

public void setScale(float scale) {
    this.scale = scale;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return Title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    Title = title;
}

public Window getWindow() {
    return window;
}

public Input getInput() {
    return input;
}
}
```

Here's my Window code:

```
package com.RougeEngine.Engine;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Window 
{
private JFrame frame;
private BufferedImage image;
private Canvas canvas;
private BufferStrategy bs;
private Graphics g;

public Window(GameContainer gc)
{
    image = new BufferedImage(gc.getWidth(),gc.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    canvas = new Canvas();
    Dimension s = new Dimension((int)(gc.getWidth() * gc.getScale()), (int)(gc.getHeight() * gc.getScale()));
    canvas.setPreferredSize(s);
    canvas.setMaximumSize(s);
    canvas.setMinimumSize(s);

    frame = new JFrame(gc.getTitle());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    canvas.createBufferStrategy(2);
    bs = canvas.getBufferStrategy();
    g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
}

public JFrame getFrame() {
    return frame;
}

public void update()
{
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(),null);
    bs.show();
}

public BufferedImage getImage() {
    return image;
}

public Canvas getCanvas() {
    return canvas;
}
```

}

Here's my Renderer code:

```
package com.RougeEngine.Engine;

import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

import com.RougeEngine.Engine.gfx.Image;

public class Renderer 
{
private int pW, pH;
private int[] p;

public Renderer(GameContainer gc)
{
    pW = gc.getWidth();
    pH = gc.getHeight();
    p = ((DataBufferInt)gc.getWindow().getImage().getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
}

public void clear()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < p.length; i++)
    {
        p[i] = 0;
    }
}

public void setPixel(int x, int y, int value)
{
    if((x < 0 || x >= pH || y < 0 || y >= pH) || value == 0xffff00ff)
    {
        return;
    }

    p[x + y * pW] = value;
}

public void drawImage(Image image, int offX, int offY)
{
    for(int y = 0; y < image.getH(); y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x < image.getW(); x++)
        {
            setPixel(x+ offX, y + offY, image.getP()[x + y * image.getW()]);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here's my Input Code:

```
package com.RougeEngine.Engine;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;

public class Input implements KeyListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, MouseWheelListener
{
private GameContainer gc;

private final int NUM_KEYS = 256;
private boolean[] keys = new boolean[NUM_KEYS];
private boolean[] keysLast = new boolean[NUM_KEYS];

private final int NUM_BUTTONS = 5;
private boolean[] buttons = new boolean[NUM_BUTTONS];
private boolean[] buttonsLast = new boolean[NUM_BUTTONS];

private int mouseX, mouseY;
private int scroll;

public Input(GameContainer gc)
{
    this.gc = gc;
    mouseX = 0;
    mouseY = 0;
    scroll = 0;

    gc.getWindow().getCanvas().addKeyListener(this);
    gc.getWindow().getCanvas().addMouseMotionListener(this);
    gc.getWindow().getCanvas().addMouseListener(this);
    gc.getWindow().getCanvas().addMouseWheelListener(this);
}

public void update()
{
    scroll = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_KEYS; i++)
    {
        keysLast[i] = keys[i];
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_BUTTONS; i++)
    {
        buttonsLast[i] = buttons[i];
    }
}

public boolean isKey(int keyCode)
{
    return keys[keyCode];
}
public boolean isKeyUp(int keyCode)
{
    return !keys[keyCode] && keysLast[keyCode];
}
public boolean isKeyDown(int keyCode)
{
    return keys[keyCode] && !keysLast[keyCode];
}

public boolean isButton(int button)
{
    return buttons[button];
}
public boolean isButtonUp(int button)
{
    return !buttons[button] && buttonsLast[button];
}
public boolean isButtonDown(int button)
{
    return buttons[button] && !buttonsLast[button];
}


@Override
public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) 
{
     scroll = e.getWheelRotation();
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) 
{
    mouseX = (int)(e.getX() / gc.getScale());
    mouseY = (int)(e.getY() / gc.getScale());
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) 
{
     mouseX = (int)(e.getX() / gc.getScale());
     mouseY = (int)(e.getY() / gc.getScale());
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) 
{

}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
{
     buttons[e.getButton()] = true;
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) 
{
     buttons[e.getButton()] = false;
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) 
{ 

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) 
{

}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
{

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
{
     keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
{
     keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;
}

public int getMouseX() {
    return mouseX;
}

public int getMouseY() {
    return mouseY;
}

public int getScroll() {
    return scroll;
}
}
```

Here's my AbstractGame:

```
package com.RougeEngine.Engine;

public abstract class AbstractGame 
{
public abstract void update(GameContainer gc, float dt);
public abstract void render(GameContainer gc, Renderer r);

}
```

Here's my Image code:

```
package com.RougeEngine.Engine.gfx;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Image 
{
private int w,h;
private int[] p;
public Image(String path)
{
    BufferedImage image = null;
    System.out.println(Image.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
    try 
    {
        image = ImageIO.read(Image.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    w = image.getWidth();
    h = image.getHeight();
    p = image.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, null, 0, w);

    image.flush();
}

public int getW() 
{
    return w;
}
public void setW(int w) 
{
    this.w = w;
}
public int getH() 
{
    return h;
}
public void setH(int h) 
{
    this.h = h;
}
public int[] getP() 
{
    return p;
}
public void setP(int[] p) 
{
    this.p = p;
}
}
```

Here's my GameManager code:

```
package com.RougeEngine.Game;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import com.RougeEngine.Engine.AbstractGame;
import com.RougeEngine.Engine.GameContainer;
import com.RougeEngine.Engine.Renderer;
import com.RougeEngine.Engine.gfx.Image;

public class GameManager extends AbstractGame
{

private Image image;

public GameManager()
{
    image = new Image("res/test.png");
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    GameContainer gc = new GameContainer(new GameManager());
    gc.start();
}

@Override
public void update(GameContainer gc, float dt) 
{
    if(gc.getInput().isKeyDown(KeyEvent.VK_A))
    {
        System.out.println("A was pressed");
    }
}

@Override
public void render(GameContainer gc, Renderer r) 
{

}

}
```

[My Hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEGhH.jpg)

[My Image (In .png format)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQTiZ.png)

Thank you for the help; I wasn't quite sure what the minimum reproducible code would be for this case so I hope the amount is okay.

Comment: What is the output produced by `System.out.println(Image.class.getResourceAsStream(path));`?  Does that URL point to something that exists?  (And the use of a class literal definitely is *not* the cause of your problem.)

Comment: The output of Image.class.getResourceAsStream(path)); is null when printed.

Comment: Is the program packaged into a .jar when you run it?  If so, check the contents of the .jar file for an entry that matches your resource path.